# Female dative case

Tags: dative

I am translating the phrase "*With a magnificent view*".

I was expecting it to be "*Mit einer herrliche Aussicht*"
However my book indicates it to be "*Mit einer herrlichen Aussicht*".

I know in the nominative case it should definitely be "*Eine herrliche Aussicht*"

Since the preposition *mit* here requires the dative case and "*Aussicht*" is a feminine noun. The indefinite article should be taking the *-er* ending and the adjective should stay as it is. (to my knowledge)

Anyone can explain why the adjective takes the *-n* ending?

Comment: What makes you believe that "the adjective should stay as it is"?

Comment: Explanation: Your knowledge is faulty. Sorry, but it’s as simple as that. Look up the endings in a grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this website for adjective endings

[Adjective Endings](https://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Adjektive/Adjektivendungen.html)

As you can see, since there is a determiner(Einer), the appropriate ending is -en